# fetch in matlab with SELECT using postgreSQL locks table long after completion

Tags: postgresql, matlab, locks

code in matlab app:

```
query = sprintf('select *,st_askml(line) from %s;', table_name);
var = fetch(connection, query);
```

This completes successfully and I get the data, the app continues running. However if I separately (in this cause within a python script) try to run "drop table if exists" on the same table, it won't work because it is locked;

[image: pg_stat_activity]

How should I change my select query in matlab so that it finishes gracefully. (btw the lock is released when I close the app).

Comment: Matlab probably started a transaction that wasn't committed and therefor the `drop table` can proceed. Check the state of the session in `pg_stat_activity` I bet it's "idle in transaction"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes it is in idle in transaction, but how do I query in such a way that that does not happen? As shown in the code, its just a select query, seems odd that the select transaction wasn't commited.

Comment: I have no idea about Matlab, but look for some "autocommit" setting and _enable_ that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, I solved it by executing commit after my query.

Answer (score 0):

I am open to hearing more details about this but I solved the problem by adding

```
execute(connection,'COMMIT');
```

after my select query.